How to correctly add columns to the original multi-index DataFrame after groupby()?
There is a DataFrame with option tickers at the zero level, prices (open, close, high, and low) at the first level, and option types at the second level (header structure: 'Ticker', 'open/close/high/low', 'Type').
The task: for each ticker, calculate the average price, then add columns with the average prices (header structure: 'Ticker', 'Average', 'Type') to the original DataFrame. My script executes almost correctly, but it corrupts the column names of the original DataFrame.
Code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_f_avg = pd.DataFrame({
    ('a1c9', 'open',  'call'):    [3,      0.50,   3.0], 
    ('a1c9', 'close', 'call'):    [4,      0.35,   3.5], 
    ('a1c9', 'high',  'call'):    [1,      0.20,   1.5],
    ('a1c9', 'low',   'call'):    [2,      0.09,   2.5],
    ('a1p9', 'open',  'put'):     [5,      0.05,   4.0], 
    ('a1p9', 'close', 'put'):     [6,      0.10,   5.5], 
    ('a1p9', 'high',  'put'):     [7,      0.20,   6.0],
    ('a1p9', 'low',   'put'):     [8,      0.31,   7.0]})
df_f_avg.columns.names = ['Ticker', 'Price', 'Type']
df_f_avg

columns_name = df_f_avg.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'open']].columns

avg_group_ticker = pd.DataFrame(data=df_f_avg.loc[:, (slice(None), ['open', 'close', 'high', 'low'], slice(None))].T.groupby('Ticker').mean().T)
avg_group_ticker.columns = columns_name
avg_group_ticker.columns._levels[1].values[:] = 'avg'

df_f_avg = pd.concat([df_f_avg, avg_group_ticker], axis=1)
df_f_avg

It turns out like this: …
Ticker                          a1c9                            a1p9    a1c9    a1p9
Price                           avg                             avg     avg     avg
Type    call    call    call    call    put     put     put     put     call    put
0       3.0     4.00    1.0     2.00    5.00    6.0     7.0     8.00    2.500   6.500
1       0.5     0.35    0.2     0.09    0.05    0.1     0.2     0.31    0.285   0.165
2       3.0     3.50    1.5     2.50    4.00    5.5     6.0     7.00    2.625   5.625


But it should look like this: …
Ticker                          a1c9                            a1p9    a1c9    a1p9
Price   open    close   high    low     open    close   high    low     avg     avg
Type    call    call    call    call    put     put     put     put     call    put
0       3.0     4.00    1.0     2.00    5.00    6.0     7.0     8.00    2.500   6.500
1       0.5     0.35    0.2     0.09    0.05    0.1     0.2     0.31    0.285   0.165
2       3.0     3.50    1.5     2.50    4.00    5.5     6.0     7.00    2.625   5.625

Questions:

How can this be fixed (P.S. this is a shortened example, in reality, there will be dozens of tickers)?
Perhaps you know a simpler and more efficient way to solve this task (simpler code, more reliable and universal, faster, less resource-intensive)?


Why yfinance is in the tags?

Because I need this for yfinance, I created a shortened DataFrame to avoid cluttering the example. And I wanted to reach out to people working with yfinance, in case they have solved a similar problem.

The issue is that you modify the original index since columns_name = df_f_avg.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'open']].columns is making a reference to it.
You must make a deep copy:
columns_name = df_f_avg.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'open']].columns.copy(deep=True)

You could also rename Price and groupby all levels:
out = df_f_avg.join(df_f_avg.rename(columns=lambda x: 'avg', level='Price')
                            .T.groupby(['Ticker', 'Price', 'Type']).mean().T
                   )

Output:
Ticker a1c9                   a1p9                    a1c9   a1p9
Price  open close high   low  open close high   low    avg    avg
Type   call  call call  call   put   put  put   put   call    put
0       3.0  4.00  1.0  2.00  5.00   6.0  7.0  8.00  2.500  6.500
1       0.5  0.35  0.2  0.09  0.05   0.1  0.2  0.31  0.285  0.165
2       3.0  3.50  1.5  2.50  4.00   5.5  6.0  7.00  2.625  5.625


Better answer than mine, +1.

Thank you very much! I tried to insert .copy() in that line, but nothing worked. But you went further and made it happen!

@VasiliyDeryuga I just added another approach which should be easier

I reopened the discussion (unchecked the accepted answer) so you can suggest another approach. Thank you.

The second approach is just amazing! It’s simpler and works faster! I’ve been studying Pandas for three months, but it feels like I’m still at the very beginning... You are very knowledgeable in Pandas. Could you please share how you achieved this? Maybe you could recommend a book or a video course?

I recommend reading the official documentation in depth. That's the best resource. Then just code ;)
